# Same input 2 different results

Tags: python, if-statement, words

I'm extremely new to programming, and I hope someone could help me. 
I'm trying to make a game where 2 players need to input words based on the last 2 letters of the word the other player placed into.
I got that part to work, but I cannot get the part which decides the winner. It's the same 2 `elif` statements but they should print out different results.

Ex.
P1: banana P2: narnia P1:ian P2:animal
So basically when one of the players fails to accomplish the task of matching the last 2 letters they lose the game

```
 used_words=[]

 while True:
     player_one=raw_input("Player one \n")
     first= list(player_one)
     player_two=raw_input("Player two \n")
     second=list(player_two)

     if first[-2:] == second[:2] and first and second not in used_words:
         used_words.append(player_one)
         used_words.append(player_two)
         continue

     elif first[-2:] != second[:2]:
         print "Player one wins! \n"
         print "The word you had to match was: ", second
         break

     elif second[:2] != first[-2:]:
         print "Player two wins!"
         print "The word you had to match was: ", first
         break

    else:
         break
```

Comment: can you explain your game with examples of 2 words

Comment: So, you have the same two `elif` statements. How can the code ever go to the second `elif`, when your condition is getting picked at the first `elif` itself? `1 != 2` is the same as `2 != 1` in programming. and gives the same result `True`.

Comment: @be_good_do_good Ex. P1:banana P2:narnia P1:ian P2:animal etc.
The goal of the game is for one of the players to not be able to come up with a word that beings with the last two letters of the previous words

Comment: @kyleas, can you provide an example of the input you have and the expected output?

Comment: You should get an input in each iteration and compare it to your history

Comment: One of your bugs is probably that the second `elif` should say `second[-2:] != first[:2]`, but there are other issues.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf   P1: banana P2: narnia P1:ian P2:animal So basically when one of the players fails to accomplish the task of matching the last 2 letters they lose the game

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yours is in the format I originally wanted, so yes, yours is the perfect one, thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your conditional `if first[-2:] == second[:2] and first and second not in used_words:` because `and first` basically is testing that `first` is not an empty string, so change it to `if first[-2:] == second[:2] and first not in used_words and second not in used_words:`. However, there are other change that should make in order to achiever what you want:

```
player_one = raw_input("Player one \n")
used_words = [player_one]

while True:
    player_two = raw_input("Player two \n")        

    if used_words[-1][-2:] != player_two[:2] and player_two not in used_words:
         print "Player one wins! \n"
         print "The word you had to match was: ", player_one
         break

    used_words.append(player_two)
    player_one = raw_input("Player one \n")

    if used_words[-1][-2:] != player_one[:2] and player_one not in used_words:
         print "Player two wins! \n"
         print "The word you had to match was: ", player_two
         break
```